# how to connect(call) wcf service on xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

i have 2 project on my solution 
1 android 
2 wcf service application

### i created a service to add my data on my database

database info:

### sql server 2014

i tested my service on debug and work fine 
info:

### connect via liq

and , add to my android project by add reference 
service added successfully 
i can see my tables , fields and ...
when i create an instance of my table on click method of my project 
android project run success but not affect on my database 
i point a break point on codes and see data to be add but no affect 
here is my codes

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Siman_Android
{
    [Activity(Label = "PersonAddActivity")]
    public class PersonAddActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);


            Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnadd);


            btn.Click += Btn_Click;

        }
   ServiceRefrence.Service1 myService = new ServiceRefrence.Service1();

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myService.Url=("http://localhost:13294/Service1.svc");
            EditText txtname = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtname);
            EditText txtfamily = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtfamily);

             myService.GetPersonAsync(txtname.Text, txtfamily.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

and my service code to add person

```
 public bool GetPerson(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        try
        {
            PersonName pr = new PersonName()
            {
                Family = LastName,
                Name = FirstName
            };
            db.PersonNames.Add(pr);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

please help!

Comment: I don't get the question. Your code runs ok but you don't see the person in your database? It seems you are using entity framework, is that right? Do you hit breakpoint in your service when GetPerson is called?

Comment: @YuriS no i see the table on database ,but nothing happen when i try to add something to database ,

Comment: can you put breakpoint in GetPerson function? Do you hit it? If yes, do you get exception in this function?

Comment: @YuriS yes i put break point and it send nothing to function just code run and not happen to database

Comment: sorry for my bad English. Do you HIT breakpoint or not when you call service?

Comment: yes i HIT breakpoint

Comment: Great. When you stop on breakpoint do you see values of parameters (string FirstName, string LastName)?

Comment: no i cant see anything

Comment: Then probably your proxy is not good. How do you generate proxy? If you put your sample project on dropbox or github I might be able to help you more

Comment: here is my codes 
please add service to it and make a service to add person on my android xamarin project
[github link(https://github.com/mzolfaghari71/Siman_Android)

Comment: I don't think you hit breakpoint because you are using localhost in Android app. You phone or simulator will not find that localhost. Where do you host your service?

Comment: how can i use the service on localhost?

Comment: You cannot. You have to expose service to internet where your Android device can consume it.

Comment: You can use local network IP address from your PC if your emulator is on the same network

Comment: no i tested ip address but no ping

Comment: I am using that and I have answered few question here about that. If both on the same network it works. Do you have internet connection in emulator from browser? I posted a picture, please check your configuration. Ping may be disabled on your machine

Comment: no i can access to internet but not fixed

Comment: what is your PC address? and what is the address on you emulator? Please provide screenshots of ipconfig on PC and Network tab on emulator

Comment: 192.168.1.3 is  my loptop ip and 1.5 is my emulator

Comment: what is 1.5 ? is it 192.168.1.5. If yes then use "http://192.168.1.3:13294/Service1.svc" Keep in midn you have to host service in IIS. If you use IIS Express it is not going to work

Comment: If you use IIS Express it is not going to work؟ why?

Comment: Because express doesn't allow any connection except from the same machine

Comment: then how can i use wit out iis?

Comment: Host in in IIS but not express

Answer (score 0):

You can use local network IP address from your PC if your emulator is on the same network. Also check if your VM has networks from Oracle box. That might create problems

[image]